# Verify a signature with bouncy castle

Tags: java, bouncycastle, signing

I inherited some code using the deprecated bouncycastle API. Before updating it to the new API I wanted to write a test to verify that I didn't change its behaviour. However, I cannot work out the correct way to verify this signature that is generated.  The code to be changed is:

```
public static byte[] createSignedData(byte[] content, X509Certificate cert, PrivateKey key)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, CMSException, IOException {

    // set up the generator
    CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();

    gen.addSigner(key, cert, CMSSignedGenerator.DIGEST_SHA1);

    // create the signed-data object
    CMSProcessable data = new CMSProcessableByteArray(content);
    CMSSignedData signed = gen.generate(data, BC_PROVIDER);

    return signed.getEncoded();
}
```

What is being returned from this code? A detached signature?
I tried to verify the signature with a small piece of code like this, but it always returns false:

```
Signature signer = Signature.getInstance(
                              "SHA1withRSA", 
                              BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
signer.initVerify(cert.getPublicKey());
signer.update(data);
return signer.verify(sig);
```

Answer (score 2):

It will return a ***detached*** signature if you use:

```
gen.generate(data, false);
```

Otherwise it will return ***signed data encapsulated in the signature***. So, if your signature is detached *(which is not your case)* in order to verify it you will need to create a new `CMSSignedData` object from your signed data bytes or `Base64` enconded `string` and also a copy of the original data as well in the constructor.

I think you're not verifying your signature the right way, also I don't know which `bouncycastle` library version are you using and you just provided a code snippet which is too vague to analyze.

This is what I did in order to sign and verify a signature using **`bcmail-jdk16-1.46.jar`**, **`bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar`** and **`jdk1.6.0_45`** (I'm assuming you are using *Java* since you never specified it, also in question tags - but hopefully *.NET* version is very similar).

You can download the ***keystore*** used in my example at: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15208254/keys/certificates.p12

Also, if you want to check if the signature verification is working fine, you can  change the certificate *(since I'm verifying against my own certificate which doesn't make sense)* by changing this line in the signature verification process, ***line 84***:

```
if (signer.verify(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider(BC_PROVIDER).build(certFromSignedData))) { ... }
```

And then loading another ***keystore*** to get another ***certificate*** from it. Just to know, the ***certificates.p12*** file I am using, contains two certificates with alias `Key1` and `Key2` so you can play around with them by signing your content with `Key1` and verifying your signature with `Key2` for example.

***e.g:***

```
// Load 'Key2' certificate from 'certificates.p12' at any place on this class after 'ks' declaration
X509Certificate certFromKeystore2 = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate("Key2");
```

Then replace ***line 84*** with this:

```
if (signer.verify(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider(BC_PROVIDER).build(certFromKeystore2))) { ... }
```

*Notice that `certFromSignedData` changed to `certFromKeystore2` and your signature verification will fail because your content was signed with `Key1`.*

---

***Java code:***

*Don't forget to change the **keystore** path in the constants!*

```
package com.example.main;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.bouncycastle.cert.X509CertificateHolder;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaCertStore;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509CertificateConverter;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSProcessableByteArray;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedData;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedDataGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSTypedData;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformation;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformationStore;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.ContentSigner;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.util.Store;

public class VerifySignature {

    static final String KEYSTORE_FILE = "keys/certificates.p12";
    static final String KEYSTORE_INSTANCE = "PKCS12";
    static final String KEYSTORE_PWD = "test";
    static final String KEYSTORE_ALIAS = "Key1";

    static final String DIGEST_SHA1 = "SHA1withRSA";
    static final String BC_PROVIDER = "BC";

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Content to be signed
        String text = "My name is Oscar";

        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        // Get keystore
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_INSTANCE);
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(KEYSTORE_FILE), KEYSTORE_PWD.toCharArray());
        Key key = ks.getKey(KEYSTORE_ALIAS, KEYSTORE_PWD.toCharArray());

        // Get private key and sign
        PrivateKey privKey = (PrivateKey) key;
        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance(DIGEST_SHA1, BC_PROVIDER);
        signature.initSign(privKey);
        signature.update(text.getBytes());

        // Build CMS
        X509Certificate certFromKeystore = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(KEYSTORE_ALIAS);
        List certList = new ArrayList();
        CMSTypedData data = new CMSProcessableByteArray(signature.sign());
        certList.add(certFromKeystore);
        Store certs = new JcaCertStore(certList);
        CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
        ContentSigner sha1Signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder(DIGEST_SHA1).setProvider(BC_PROVIDER).build(privKey);
        gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider(BC_PROVIDER).build()).build(sha1Signer, certFromKeystore));
        gen.addCertificates(certs);
        CMSSignedData signedData = gen.generate(data, true);

        // Verify signature
        Store store = signedData.getCertificates(); 
        SignerInformationStore signers = signedData.getSignerInfos(); 
        Collection c = signers.getSigners(); 
        Iterator it = c.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) { 
            SignerInformation signer = (SignerInformation) it.next(); 
            Collection certCollection = store.getMatches(signer.getSID()); 
            Iterator certIt = certCollection.iterator();
            X509CertificateHolder certHolder = (X509CertificateHolder) certIt.next();
            X509Certificate certFromSignedData = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider(BC_PROVIDER).getCertificate(certHolder);
            if (signer.verify(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider(BC_PROVIDER).build(certFromSignedData))) {
                System.out.println("Signature verified");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Signature verification failed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```