# How verify digital signature in Message Java?

Tags: java, jira, jakarta-mail, digital-signature, jira-plugin

I try to make custom mail handler for Jira on Java which has to verify digital signature of message if that message has a signature. But I can't understand how to make it.

1. I have `javax.mail.Message message` and how can I check if it has signature?
2. And if message has signature to verify this, as I understand, I have to do smth like that:

```java
//create a Signature instance
 Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
//initialize the Signature object for verification which takes a public key
signature.initVerify(publicKey);
//add the received message bytes to the signature object
String body = MailUtils.getBody(message);
byte[] messageBytes = body.getBytes(); 
signature.update(messageBytes);
//And finally, check the signature
boolean isCorrect = signature.verify(receivedSignature);
```

But how can I get algorithm, publicKey and receivedSignature from recieved javax.mail.Message message?

Comment: Signed mails are not easily (to say the least!) processable using only `javax.mail.Message`, as there is a **huge** lot of stuff that goes onto signing a mail (see PKCS7, CMS, and S/MIME standards). I suggest switching to a higher level library, such as BouncyCastle. You can find official code samples here https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/tree/master/mail/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/mail/smime/examples or on SO : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451744/verify-a-signature-with-bouncy-castle ,

Comment: Unfortunately in jira plugin I can use only javax.mail.Message. That method ```public boolean handleMessage(Message message, MessageHandlerContext context)``` invokes automatically with ```javax.mail.Message```.

Comment: Or may be I can wrap Message in to BouncyCastle?

Comment: Yes you can : https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/mail/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/mail/smime/validator/SignedMailValidator.java#L116

Comment: Oh, thanks I'll try.

Comment: So, I can use ```MimeMessage``` because it's implimentation of ```javax.mail.MessageCould```? And can you explain, please, where I can get signature in message? As I understand message it is a List of 2 byte arrays (the message and the signature), algorithm is known, but where I can get public key, I suppose it has to be into message or it is transmitted separately?

Comment: The MIME message holds it all. The message, the file attachments, the signature, the certificates used to sign, and it may even contain the certificate chain and revocation lists. It has it all. How to access it depends on how the mail has been created, and is library dependant. In BouncyCastle, see the SignedMailValdator to see how it can be done. More importantly : *do not do it yourself*. **Nobody** can get it right, it is too complex. Let the library handle the signature verification by itself. You may peek into the mail content/signature, but not to validate it yourself.

Comment: I see the SignedMailValdator class and don't understand how can I validate signature. I have to create instance of `SignedMailValidator` with casted type of message `public SignedMailValidator(MimeMessage message, PKIXParameters param)` and what next? Call `validateSignatures(PKIXParameters pkixParam)`? And where I can get that PKIXParameters? Don't understand anything :(

Comment: The link given above (https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/tree/master/mail/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/mail/smime/examples) is a sample of a signed email verification. But if you do not have enough knowledge (yet) of what KeyStore, TrustStore, trust anchors, ca certificates, (...) are then you have some studying to do before tackling on this issue. SO's format is about helping in specific *programming* issues, and is not well suited to help you discover about these topcis. If you reach a point where it should work, but does not because of an exception, etc..., then would we be able to help.

Comment: @Duxa, you can find a "simple" example for validating an S/MIME signature using `SignedMailValidator` in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63023657/320594